# Help with finding the product of elements of a finite order

Tags: group-theory

Let G be the plane symmetry group of the infinite strip of equally spaced H's shown below:

$$ H \hspace{0.5cm} H  \hspace{0.5cm} \color{\red}{|}  \hspace{0.5cm} H  \hspace{0.5cm} |  \hspace{0.5cm} H  \hspace{0.5cm} H $$

Let x be the reflection about Axis 1 ($\color{\red}{|} $) and let y be the reflection about axis 2 (|). Calculate |x|, |y|, and |xy|. Must the product of elements of finite order have finite order?

Comment: No. You should prove that $xy$ translates the chain of $H$s by two position, and thus has infinite order.

Comment: Note that this is exercise 10 in the additional exercises to chapters 1-4 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that $|x|=|y|=2$ because $x$ and $y$ are reflections. From the other side, if we consecutively enumerate the H’s by integers, then the composition $xy$ will be correspond to 
shift $n\mapsto n+2$, and hence it has an infinite order.

Comment: Note that the shift is a left shift. So it would be more intuitive if you wrote $$ n \mapsto n - 2$$